# Step by Step to Connect to ElectrumX via Nodejs

Tags: transactions, wallet, electrum, balance

I am developing a simple app that will need to retrieve BTC wallet Address Balance and relative transactions

Initially I thought to use some existing APIs (btc.com, blockchain.com etc.), but the limitation in terms of request rates do not fit my project...

Looking at other options it seems that my best bet is:

- Identify an ElectrumX public server
- Request blockchain.scripthash.get_balance (via JSON RPC)
- Request blockchain.scripthash.get_history (via JSON RPC)

now, I am not a techy person, but I like to learn and play around :) therefore I need to "translate the theory into practice"... where do I start? is there a step by step guide "for dummie" tutorial?

Thank you all